# Today's best approaches on scalable high-performance PHP-applications

Tags: php, database, performance, scalability

We are in the startup build phase of a new PHP webapp that will be placed onto a cloud server to allow fast and easy up/downscaling when customers will grow or decrease in numbers. Most probably, we will use a PHP framework (Codeigniter) to keep development speed high.

Our next step is to implement features for increased performance (cacheing etc) and choosing which databases to use.

Solutions like memcached and eaccelerator is of course what comes up into our minds at first, but are there even better solutions available out there today?

Is mySQL really yesterdays choice when high performance is in focus?

So, please - share your ideas and thoughts on how to create the basic cornerstones for a high performance webapp!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things you should know:

1. 8 or 9 out of 10 startups fail; and
2. Nothing exceptional is required to get you to 1-5 million uniques a month. If and when you get to 5+ million uniques ou will probably have rewritten your application 2-6 times.

So basically don't worry about this "problem" until you have a problem.

Also cloud servers are good for burst usage but the data fees tend to make them a bad choice for constant usage. The typical progression is:

1. Shared hosting (you may skip this);
2. VPS (you might skip this too);
3. Dedicated server; then
4. Co-location.

As for what tools to use, well that depends entirely on your app. MySQL is a fine choice for most circumstances. An opcode cache like APC or eAccelerator is typically a good idea. Memcache can be useful for certain kinds of applications.

Comment: I would agree with this @Cletus except for some really bad code I saw the other day -- I would say it is easy to not be able to handle 1-5 million uniques if you have some bad coders at the application or data tier.  Don't skimp on the programmers.

Comment: @Hogan: sure you can write bad code in anything but the question isn't so much "how do I write good code?" (which is the subject of a complete education, not a single question) but rather "do I have to do anything special?" to which the answer is "no".

Comment: @Cletus Well, overanalysing details in early stages of a project does often lead, in one way or another, to either failure or that the needs of high performance or scalability never will appear - just like you said. However there's probably more good resources out there than those of which I know, that can improve both speed and performance (in the long run scalability) and to get these implemented as early as possible would in my opinion be awesome.

Comment: @Cletus Besides the economical part of using VPS as a main hosting supplier, wouldn't you agree that it is really good to be able to up and downscale on demand and in any stage of the business development have bigger costs than necessary?

Comment: @Industrial cloud services make sense when you need a lot of temporary VMs (eg http://litmusapp.com/ use cloud VMs to create browsers to snapshot pages) or when you have huge burst needs. Most people don't have either problem. Ultimately colocation is where it's at.

Comment: @Industrial the problem with planning for scalability is that what you think will be the problem rarely is. Are there things you should know? Probably but I don't know what you know. What's more important is having a good page design, a good UI, fast loading pages and of course a great product.

Comment: @ Cletus - You're totally right. All those things are essential. However please let me know if there's anything better available out there than an approach including memcached and mySQL.

Comment: Can I just step in and question whether you think this still applies? I agree with everything you've said, but this is a 4 year old reply; just curious to how you now perceive it?

Answer (score 6):

I think you should focus on building a good app, and worry about performance once you have a big enough user base  that it matters.  That isn't to say you should code without performance in mind. However it sounds like you're trying to optimize before you even have any real users.  Any performance tuning you do would be theoretical, and not based on what actually happens with your particular application.  You'll have to have a lot of users before you can see the usage patterns and the bottle necks that result specifically in your application.  Also, if you're really worried that much about performance at this level, using PHP is not the way to go.  PHP can be made fast, but compared to other languages which are compiled, it will always be slower.   There is no answer.   It all depends on what your application is doing.  PHP can work fine if most of the server time is spent somewhere else like in the database.  MySQL can be fine depending on what you're doing, and what kind of information you are trying to use it for.

Comment: Hi Kibbee! Thanks for your reply. What you are saying is completely true, trying to optimize before real users are apparent is like expanding a house before building it.

However, no one wants to build their house without the best available foundation. Sorry for the metaphoric approach, but my question is based on which features that are available to choose and use in order to create the best possible foundation on top of PHP when having performance in mind. What is a fast compiled language in your opinion?